# Having an issue with sending a string as an argument in a function in Google apps script

Tags: javascript, string, function, google-apps-script, arguments

I'm trying to pass a string of text as an argument to a function in a Google Apps Script. For some reason only if it's one word does it work (maybe even two words) but if it's a sentence the function doesn't work. I tried assigning the string to a variable but it doesn't help. any insight of what I'm doing wrong? see examples below.

THIS WORKS

```
function startMessage(body,to,from){
  var d = new Date();
  var time = d.toLocaleString();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Message Queue');
  ss.appendRow([body,time]);
  sendSms(from,to,"TEST");
}
```

THIS DOES NOT WORK

```
function startMessage(body,to,from){
  var d = new Date();
  var time = d.toLocaleString();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Message Queue');
  ss.appendRow([body,time]);
  sendSms(from,to,"Please reply YES to confirm and send the message to all contacts");
}
```

THIS DOES NOT WORK

```
function startMessage(body,to,from){
  var d = new Date();
  var time = d.toLocaleString();
  var reply = "Please reply YES to confirm and send the message to all contacts";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Message Queue');
  ss.appendRow([body,time]);
  sendSms(from,to,reply);
}
```

HERE IS THE sendSms() CODE

```
function sendSms(to,from,body){
  var config = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Config');
  var accountSid = config.getRange(3,2).getValue();
  var authToken = config.getRange(4,2).getValue();

  var messagesUrl = "https://xxxxxxxx.signalwire.com/api/laml/2010-04-01/Accounts/"+accountSid+"/Messages.json";
  
  var payload = {
    "To": to,
    "From" : from,
    "Body" : body
  };
  
  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload,
  };
  
  options.headers = {    
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(accountSid+':'+authToken)
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(messagesUrl, options);
}
```

HERE IS THE `doPost()` THAT INITIATES EVERYTHING

```
function doPost(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var incomingMessages = ss.getSheetByName('Incoming Messages');
  var config = ss.getSheetByName('Config');
  var recognizedNumber = config.getRange(5,2).getValue();
  var d = new Date();
  var time = d.toLocaleString();
  
  var from = e.parameter.From;
  var body = e.parameter.Body;
  var to = e.parameter.To;
  
if (from == recognizedNumber){
    if(body.toLowerCase() == 'yes'){
    signalWire(from,to);
    }else{
    startMessage(body,to,from);
    }
}else{
  incomingMessages.appendRow([time,from,body]);
}
```

}

Comment: This looks like an issue with the `sendSms()` function. Please show that code.

Comment: Your example is not a [mcve] because sendSms is not defined.

Comment: The spreadsheet code is irrelevant.

Comment: I edited the question to include the `sendSms()` function, Please let me know if that helps

Comment: and the `doPost()` function.

Comment: try: `  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : JSON.stringify(payload),
  };`

Answer (score 0):

OK guys I think I figured it out. I checked the response of the Url Fetch of the `sendSms()` function and the function completed successfully. The issue was that the sms were not being delivered for some reason so its a third party issue nothing seems to be wrong with the code.

Thanks.